# If else statement conflict for device orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I created an app that retrieves Web Service API data. I am able to display that data in a list view. This works fine except that I want to use a spinner instead of a listview when in portrait mode. I created code 2 xml files: one in portrait with a spinner and one in landscape with a listview and code that checks for these orientation changes but unfortunately the app crashes. Can anyone explain what is going on?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.master_fragment, container, false);
        // Simply loads the available data in receipeList to Master Fragment.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, receipeList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }else {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.master_fragment_spinner, container, false);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, receipeList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Just let Android load the correct XML.

Comment: The problem is that I created 2 xml files. But when I replace the ListView with a Spinner in the xml the app crashes. So I am not sure about how to make the app load the correct xml

Comment: You did not answer, **why** are you trying to do this?  Why not use the default mechanism for loading layouts?

Comment: The reason I did this is because I have to use a spinner instead of a ListView in portrait mode. When I implement a spinner instead of a listview the app crashes. I believe it is because I have code that works for a list view but it does not work for a spinner. What would my options be? To create code that would specifically work work for a spinner in portrait mode and then more code for a listview in landscape? I apologize for any confusion. This is my fourth week with android SDK. Thanks :)

Comment: That's not what I asked. I'm sorry, I don't know how to ask the question in a clearer way, let me try different words.  Why are you trying to load the layouts yourself instead of letting Android do it for you?

Comment: Thanks for all your patience. I want to load the layouts myself because when I let android load them for me it crashes. I believe that the reason for the crash is that I am trying to use the same code used for a listview with a spinner. If this does not make sense I will understand if this questions is marked negatively. Again. thank you for all your valuable time good Sir.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, for info.  The correct approach is to let Android do it and fix the bug you have.  Go back to doing the **right** way, then start a new question to solve your problem.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test about orientation, just put your xml file for protrait in `/res/layout` and the xml file for landscape in `/res/layout-land` and Android will load the correct XML